# Delete/Merge rows based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+------------------+
|    id      |  order_id | origin | type     | delivery_id | return_requested | 
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+------------------+
| 42         | 420       |  US    | DELIVERY | d-UUID      |        0         |
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+------------------+
| 43         | 420       |  US    | RETURN   | r-UUID      |        1         |
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+------------------+
| 48         | 520       |  US    | DELIVERY | d-UUID      |        0         |
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+------------------+
| 50         | 520       |  US    | RETURN   | r-UUID      |        1         |
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+------------------+
```

Where `d-UUID` or `r-UUID` are unique ids with a prefix (`d` for delivery and `r` for return).

Currently I changed the way I insert data in the database and instead of adding a new row every time, I am now finding the order_id and updating the existing row.

For example if an order was returned, I will now find the one with id=42 and update it from type 'DELIVERY' to 'RETURN' and 'return_requested' from false to true while the `delivery_id` stays the same. 
(the two columns type and return_requested are a bit redundant, but that's for another day)

But I have a lot of old entries now with `delivery_id` beginning with `r-` which I want to delete/merge with the rows where the `order_id` is the same.

I have the following SQL that finds these rows:

```
SELECT * FROM delivery
WHERE order_id IN (
    SELECT order_id FROM delivery
    WHERE return_requested = 1
    AND delivery_id LIKE '%R-%'
)
```

But I cannot figure out how to merge these rows. In the end I want to achieve this:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+------------------+
|    id      |  order_id | origin | type     | delivery_id | return_requested | 
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+------------------+
| 42         | 420       |  US    | RETURN   | d-UUID      |        1         |
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+------------------+
| 48         | 520       |  US    | RETURN   | d-UUID      |        1         |
+------------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+------------------+
```

EDIT: I am looing for an update/delete statement that mutates the data in the database, not a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming not all orders have returns, you need a left join to get your desired output:

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    o.order_id,
    o.origin,
    CASE WHEN r.id NULL THEN o.type ELSE r.type END AS type,
    o.delivery_id,
    CASE WHEN r.id NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS return_requested,
FROM delivery as o
LEFT JOIN delivery as r
    ON RIGHT(o.delivery_id, len(o.delivery_id)-2) = RIGHT(r.delivery_id, len(r.delivery_id)-2)
```

To "MERGE" the records, you can do this:

```
UPDATE o
SET 
    o.type = 'RETURN'
    o.return_requested = 1
from delivery as o
INNER JOIN delivery as r
    ON RIGHT(o.delivery_id, len(o.delivery_id)-2) = RIGHT(r.delivery_id, len(r.delivery_id)-2)

DELETE FROM delivery
WHERE LEFT(delivery_id, 2) = 'r-'
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want - I want to merge the rows together resulting in deletion from the rows with `delivery_id` beginning with `r-...` and updating the rows with `d-...` - in other words I need a sort of UPDATE / DELETE statement.

Comment: You can select the above into a temp table, truncate your delivery table, and then insert from temp back to delivery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY and aggregate functions. To get the result as single output

SELECT order_id,origin,type,delivery_id,return_requested FROM delivery where group by order_id,origin,type,delivery_id,return_requested_id

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to just SELECT the rows, I can do that much simpler. What I want is to merge the rows together resulting in deletion from the rows with `delivery_id` beginning with `r-...` and updating the rows with `d-...`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any guarantee that the `id` of the field `delivery_id` is always greater than current id you want to update, as your code example shows, and you don't mind having hardcoded values in your `SET` clause, you can use that query:

```
UPDATE delivery
    SET  tipo = 'RETURN',
         return_requested = 1
WHERE order_id IN (
    SELECT order_id FROM delivery
    WHERE return_requested = 1 AND delivery_id = 'r-UUID'
    GROUP BY order_id, id
    HAVING id = max(id)
) AND tipo = 'DELIVERY'
```